# Can a client be connected to multiple rooms at one instance of time?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Title: multi chat app using express and socket.io

I am trying to make a chat application, in which each room is created for a pair of online users, so that broadcasting is easy if I know the room and clients present in it.

I am wondering to know is it actually possible to be a client connected to more than one rooms at a time.

I tried to figure it out but could not. Please tell me if it is possible at all or if any alternative(easy) approach is available

Comment: Of course. A client can be in several rooms. Just call `.join(roomName)` for every room.

Comment: Thank you DerM for the clarification. One more thing - I am thinking to create a seperate room for every pair of users. It that a good way?

Comment: I don't know, depends what your requirement is.
I wouldn't do it because for n users you would create (n²-n)/2 rooms.